# Static and non static in java?

Tags: java, static, non-static

Error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   setSelectedInfoRole(SelectOption) from the type
>   PeopleInfoViewModel.PeopleInfoData

Here's code:

```
    @Command
    @NotifyChange({ "peopleInfoList", "selectedFolderInfo" })
    public void encryptInfo() {
        Set selectedPeopleInfo=peopleInfoList.getSelection();
        if (selectedPeopleInfo == null) {
            showError(pageResourceBundle.getText("PLS_SELECT_AN_INFO_TO_CRYPT"));
            return;
        } 
        List<PeopleInfoRecord> folderRecord = new ArrayList<PeopleInfoRecord>();


        for (Object selectedObj : selectedPeopleInfo) {
            if (selectedObj instanceof PeopleInfoData) {
                PeopleInfoData peopleInfoData = (PeopleInfoData) selectedObj;
                ValidInfoRow validInfoRow = Services.folderService().findValidInfoByInfoCode(peopleInfoData.getPeopleInfoRecord().getInfoCode());

                if (InfoType.CHOOSE.equals(validInfoRow.getInfoType())) {
                    if (!CsdcStringUtils.isBlank(peopleInfoData.getPeopleInfoRecord().getInfoValue(), true)) {
                        PeopleInfoData.setSelectedInfoRole(new SelectOption<String>(peopleInfoData.getPeopleInfoRecord().getInfoValue()));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

In above  method line

```
   PeopleInfoData.setSelectedInfoRole(new SelectOption<String>(peopleInfoData.getPeopleInfoRecord().getInfoValue()));
```

give error.

Here's Pojo class:

```
public class PeopleInfoData {
        private ListModelList<SelectOption<String>> infoobj;

        private PeopleInfoRecord peopleInfoRecord;
        private SelectOption<String> selectedInfoRole;


        public SelectOption<String> getSelectedInfoRole() {
            return selectedInfoRole;
        }

        public void setSelectedInfoRole(SelectOption<String> selectedInfoRole) {
            this.selectedInfoRole = selectedInfoRole;
        }

        public ListModelList<SelectOption<String>> getInfoobj() {
            return infoobj;
        }

        public void setInfoobj(ListModelList<SelectOption<String>> infoobj) {
            this.infoobj = infoobj;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setSelectedInfoRole()` is a `non-static` method and you're trying to call it in a `static` manner `PeopleInfoData.setSelectedInfoRole` which is wrong. You need to create a object of that class and then call that method.

```
new PeopleInfoData().setSelectedInfoRole(new SelectOption<String>(peopleInfoData.getPeopleInfoRecord().getInfoValue()));
```

But it looks as that you already have a object created for that class. You need to use that object to call this method.

```
PeopleInfoData peopleInfoData = (PeopleInfoData) selectedObj;
peopleInfoData.setSelectedInfoRole(new SelectOption<String>(peopleInfoData.getPeopleInfoRecord().getInfoValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in this line: `PeopleInfoData.setSelectedInfoRole(new SelectOption<String>(peopleInfoData.getPeopleInfoRecord().getInfoValue()))` is the capital 'P'. Your variable is called  `peopleInfoData` You're trying to access the method like it's a static method of `PeopleInfoData`.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Java Language Specification, section 8.4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2).

A `static` class method implies that it is a general utility method for that class, not specific to actual objects of that class. A `static` method, among other things, cannot refer to `this`, as yours does.

I expect you meant to write `peopleInfoData` on that line instead of `PeopleInfoData`, so you would refer to the object itself, and not its class. Otherwise, Java will not know which object `this` you are referring to when this method gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the class name instead of the variable name. Just use a lowercase "p" and you'll be fine. You can't make a static reference (using the class name) to a non static method. You need to use an instance of that object to access a non static method.